# How much does fuel cost?

Tags: mass-effect-3

I was wondering what the cost per unit of fuel is in Mass Effect 3?  I like to spend good money on stuff on the market, but I obviously need to keep a little in reserve for fuel.  Knowing how much fuel costs per unit would go a long way to helping me plan my outings.

Comment: Do note that you can get a free fill-up by docking at the Citadel.  The loading screens might make it somewhat more painful, but if you're low on cash, it's a good alternative.

Comment: also note there's no penalty for running out of fuel, you're booted back to the Mass Relay. You can get everything with never paying for fuel if you're willing to sacrifice some time for extra citadel trips

Comment: @agent86 why didn't someone tell me this earlier?  I could have saved so much money.

Comment: The loading times at the citadel aren't that bad.  But it's still nice to be able to refuel in space.  In any case, you guys have helped me to further my personal quest of buying all of the fish and all of the models in game.  :-P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fuel cost 1 credit pr unit, but as others have mentioned you can always just go back to Citadel and there is no penalty for running out you just return to nearest mass relay.

Comment: I wish real gas was only $1 per unit (gallon)...

Comment: @Fluttershy without specifying units, it's probably a Planck unit (volume), so more like [$9 × 10¹⁰¹ per gallon](https://www.google.com/search?btnG=1&pws=0&q=1+USD+%2F+(planck+length)**3+in+USD%2Fgallon)